List of counter examples + statistics of Greenberg's universal
I could not find a list of counter examples/ statistics of Greenberg's linguistic universals.
There are numbers that I could find relevant information on WALS. There are some I could not find anything. eg. number 30: If the verb has categories of person-number or if it has categories of gender, it always has tense-mode categories.
I like this database very much:
List of rara
I would like to know the universality of each of his number.
